# Gmail action buttons *inside* emails?

Tags: google-schemas

Gmail actions seem like a really cool feature, but their placement at the far right of the subject line means I invariably miss them, even when I know they exist (i.e. for a MailChimp confirmation email).

It would make a lot more sense to me to place these buttons *inside* the email, as part of the regular content. Is this supported by the current API? Or are there any plans to support it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plans to show more interactive cards like the ones currently used for flight reservations, but for the moment actions will only be shown on the subject line.

There are no plans for the API to add buttons inside the email as part of the content, as the content is HTML defined by the sender and HTML already supports buttons.

Comment: I guess what I had in mind was an API to wire up these HTML buttons. One can always dream…